# Algorithm for implementing the modulus "%" operator?

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point, integers

How can an efficient modulus operator be implemented?

Here's a naive way of defining `A % B`:

> given $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ (represented as `int`)
>
> while $a > b$ : $(a,b) \mapsto (a-b,b)$
>
> return $a$

This could be very slow. E.g. $(a,b) = (10^7, 13)$.  I could be subtracting 13's for a long time.

---

One more possibility is that `%` is defined in terms of another infix operator `/` as well as the `int` function (here in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660997/implementing-the-modulo-operator-as-a-function-in-c) and verbatim in Python):

> `a % b = a - (b * int(a/b))`

---

This is probably not how Python implements it's [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python) operator (as it makes a call to C or Fortran).   The `%` operator is need to reduce fractions or compute [GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python)'s.

Here are some examples of truncation and division from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t “implement the modulus operator”. You check wit the standards for your programming language how it is defined, and that’s what you implement. For languages like C, C++, Objective-C, Swift and many others, a % b is *defined* as a - b * (a/ b). And that’s what you implement.

To be efficient: Most processors have built-in division and multiplication. Many support faster implementation of division if b is known. And at last if you want to know whether a % b = 0, you can do that without calculating a / b exactly which makes it a bit faster.

Comment: OK, so that's *definition*  of `%`.  I found this article on [binary multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier) on Wikipedia which links to more articles on [multiplication](http://www.andraka.com/multipli.php).

Comment: perhaps I should ask at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: ..which just moves the question on to "algorithm for implementing the `/` operator". Because `gcc` on ARM generates a function call for this operator, and the library that's supposed to supply the implementation, `libgcc` supplies only ARM code not THUMB code rendering `/` and `%` unusable on some devices. Still that definition is useful, now I only have to implement *one* operator.

Answer (score -1):

My own mathematical implementation of `mod(float x, float y)` may be useful in some cases

$$\frac{y}2 - \frac{y}{\pi} \arctan \left ( \cot \left( \frac{x}y\pi \right) \right)$$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2uczus4jyr

Comment: How exactly this answers the question? arctan and cot operations both involve modulus operator on floating point number, which is slower than integer modulus, so it cannot be efficient at all.